# Netty ChannelFuture performance

Tags: netty

I have a piece of code that checks if the ChannelHandlerContext WriteandFlush is successful (to ensure message has been sent successfully before sending the next message)

```
    logger.debug("Writing '" + message + "' to channel now");
    ctx.writeAndFlush(message.getMessage());

    ChannelFutureListener cfl = new ChannelFutureListener() {
      @Override
      public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
        if (future.isSuccess()) {
          // Message was successfully sent
          logger.debug("Message '" + message + "' sent successfully");
```

The problem I have is the the operationComplete is taking just over a second after the writeandflush and this is killing my server performance. 
Does anybody know why this is taking so long?

Is it best-practice to check the success of a writeandflush this way before continuing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle messages at a async framework is just to send them. Netty will take care of the messages and make them arrive in the proper order.

The reason it takes so long before your ChannelFutureListener is called, is because Netty will only call it when the write + flush has fully succeeded. When this happens, the following occurs:

1. You call `writeAndFlush`
2. Netty writes it to the underlying pipeline (quick)
3. Netty flushes the whole pipeline (quick)
4. Flush return success if the data has arrived at the other endpoint, this can take some time
5. Then your listener is called

The advantage of this method is that you know you the other side has fully received the data at the moment the listener is called, and that its safe to call methods like close at that moment.

If you want to send multiple packets to the same connection, instead of calling repeated `writeAndFlush`, you should instead call `write` for every packet, and then send a `flush()` call after the last packet, this way all pckets will be processed simultaneously.